# Does Prisma support multi-valued index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, indexing, prisma

MySQL 8.0.17 and above supports [multi-valued indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued) for indexing columns which are a JSON array.

Creating such an index requires specific use of DDL, like this:

```
INDEX zips( (CAST(custinfo->'$.zipcode' AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)) )
```

The question is how to get this declaration done in the Prisma schema.

The documentation for defining indexes seems to have nothing about this. The equivalent in Postgres (GIN index) is [covered](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/indexes#generalized-inverted-index-gin) and has a specific syntax in the Prisma schema: (`@@index([value(ops: JsonbPathOps)], type: Gin)`

I guess this means that support for multi-valued MySQL index doesn't exist, but maybe I'm missing something?

Any other thoughts / ideas on this?

Is this maybe something that's coming soon in Prisma?

Comment: There is no mention of Multi-Valued index in documentation and I wasn't able to find any existing feature requests for it, I would recommend you to create a feature request with this link: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md&title=

Comment: Will do unless someone has a better idea here

Comment: Frameworks do not implement everything that the underlying database engine implements.  Does Prisma allow you to write "raw SQL"?

Comment: @RickJames no. There would be pros and cons to allowing that.
Specifically, multi-values index seems like a pretty useful feature to support, and the equivalent feature is already supported for Postgres. So IMHO it would make sense for support to be added.

Comment: @orange77 - _Lots_ of optimization questions I answer here involve "composite" (multi_column_) indexes.  You should be able to connect directly to MySQL to add/modify `INDEXes`, even if you cannot send a 'better' query through Prima.  (And, yes, lots of my optimization answers require rewriting the queries.)

Comment: @orange77 - Oh, you are referring to the special situation where a JSON field has multiple values; there is a new type of index that allows for that.  Without JSON, you would, instead, create a table with multiple _rows_ for the "multi-valued" pseudo-column in JSON.  I think I need to see sample data (that shows examples of "multi-value", plus a query that "needs" such an INDEX.